# how to read the plain text of a non-encrypted Telegram messenger packet?

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, type-conversion, telegram

I am interested in observing how Telegram Messenger works. therefore I captured the first few packets of connection between an android Telegram client and Telegram servers via Wireshark software. The thing is, although there's no handshake to establish a SSL connection, since the port #443 is being used on the server side, the contents of the packets (which must be using TCP, according to Telegram FAQs) are unintelligible. The point is there's no SSL going on here, but since the port 443 is used Wireshark assumes that it's an SSL packet, and based on that assumption puts the TCP data into SSL data field. I read somewhere that they use a BLOB filter but I do not know how accurate that hypothesis is.
I don't know if there's any righteous conversion. I would appreciate any comment.

[Hex and ascii dump of ssl data field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC0f4.jpg)

Comment: See [MTProto Mobile Protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) and the [FAQ for the Technically Inclined](https://core.telegram.org/techfaq).

Comment: Document helps a bit, but does not explicitly says which conversion is being used, therefore I tried many conversions which none of them worked.